# specific color contour

Tags: matlab, colors, contour

I need to use all these commands together. The problem is the output is not black.

```
contour(f',[0.002]);
az = 90;
el = 90;
view(az, el);
axis off 
set(gcf,'color',[1 1 1]);
```

I also tried

```
[C,h] = contourf(f');
Cld = get(h, 'Children');
for j=1:length(Cld)
if strcmp(get(Cld(j), 'Type'), 'patch')
    Iso = get(Cld(j), 'CData');
    if Iso<-.00002
        set(Cld(j), 'cdata', 0);
    elseif Iso>=-.00002 && Iso<0.00002
        set(Cld(j), 'cdata', 0);
    end
end
end
```

but it gives all contours while I need just one with specific value, i.e., 0.002.
Thank you very much beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Do you just want a simple black contour plot? Try this:

```
contour(f', [0.002], 'LineColor', [0 0 0]);
```